# How to multiply rows in a tibble to another corresponding rows in another tibble

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, tibble

I have two tibbles, first is this.

```r
input_data <- tibble::tribble(

 # Number of samples can be more than 2.
 # Number of genes around 24K

 ~Genes,     ~Sample1, ~Sample2,
 "Ncr1",       8.2,      10.10,
 "Il1f9",      3.2,      20.30,
 "Stfa2l1",    2.3,      0.3,
 "Klra10",     5.5,      12.0,
 "Dcn",        1.8,      0,
 "Cxcr2",      1.3,      1.1,
 "Foo",        20,       70
)

input_data
#> # A tibble: 7 × 3
#>     Genes Sample1 Sample2
#>     <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1    Ncr1     8.2    10.1
#> 2   Il1f9     3.2    20.3
#> 3 Stfa2l1     2.3     0.3
#> 4  Klra10     5.5    12.0
#> 5     Dcn     1.8     0.0
#> 6   Cxcr2     1.3     1.1
#> 7     Foo    20.0    70.0
```

The second one is this,

```r
fixed_score <- tibble::tribble(
  # Number of non genes column can be more than 5.

  ~Genes,       ~B,     ~Mac,   ~NK,    ~Neu,   ~Stro,
  "Ncr1",    0.087,     0.151,  0.495,  0.002,  0.004,
  "Il1f9",   0.154,     0.099,  0.002,  0.333,  0.005,  
  "Stfa2l1", 0.208,     0.111,  0.002,  0.332,  0.005, 
  "Klra10",  0.085,     0.139,  0.496,  0.001,  0.004, 
  "Dcn",     0.132,     0.358,  0.003,  0.003,  0.979, 
  "Cxcr2",   0.132,     0.358,  0.003,  0.003,  0.979
)

fixed_score
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>     Genes     B   Mac    NK   Neu  Stro
#>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    Ncr1 0.087 0.151 0.495 0.002 0.004
#> 2   Il1f9 0.154 0.099 0.002 0.333 0.005
#> 3 Stfa2l1 0.208 0.111 0.002 0.332 0.005
#> 4  Klra10 0.085 0.139 0.496 0.001 0.004
#> 5     Dcn 0.132 0.358 0.003 0.003 0.979
#> 6   Cxcr2 0.132 0.358 0.003 0.003 0.979
```

What I want to do is to multiply value each of `Sample1` (and `Sample2`)
with the corresponding gene row values in `fixed_score`.

Yielding this for `Sample1`

```r
              B    Mac     NK    Neu   Stro
 Ncr1    0.7134 1.2382 4.0590 0.0164 0.0328
 Il1f9   0.4928 0.3168 0.0064 1.0656 0.0160
 Stfa2l1 0.4784 0.2553 0.0046 0.7636 0.0115
 Klra10  0.4675 0.7645 2.7280 0.0055 0.0220
 Dcn     0.2376 0.6444 0.0054 0.0054 1.7622
 Cxcr2   0.1716 0.4654 0.0039 0.0039 1.2727
```

So for in the result above we get the value by the following:

```r
Ncr1 (sample1)  x Ncr1   (fixed_score B) = 8.2 x 0.87  = 7.134
Il1f9 (sample1) x  Il1f9 (fixed_score B) = 3.2 x 0.154 = 0.493
```

Result for `Sample2` is this:

```r
              B    Mac     NK    Neu   Stro
 Ncr1    0.8787 1.5251 4.9995 0.0202 0.0404
 Il1f9   3.1262 2.0097 0.0406 6.7599 0.1015
 Stfa2l1 0.0624 0.0333 0.0006 0.0996 0.0015
 Klra10  1.0200 1.6680 5.9520 0.0120 0.0480
 Dcn     0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 Cxcr2   0.1452 0.3938 0.0033 0.0033 1.0769
```

How can I do that with data.table or dplyr? Since we the number of rows 
is very large. Preferable to have fast method.

Comment: Do you want  two datasets as output?

Comment: @akrun: a list of data frames or list of tibbles.

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(c("Sample1", "Sample2"), function(x) {x1 <- merge(fixed_score, input_data[c("Genes", x)], by = "Genes"); x1[-1] <- x1[2:6]*x1[,7]; x1} )`

Comment: @akrun How can I modify it so that the function takes two nibbles: `input_data` and `fixed_score` as input. Now you separate sample column names from the tibble. Also need that for clarity for future code maintenance.

Comment: It is because you wanted two datasets as output one for Sample1 and other for Sample2.  To separate sample column names `input_data %>% select(-matches("Sample"))` (if you don't wnt it) or remove the `-`

Comment: If you want this to be fast, just work with matrices instead of tibbles. Something like `unlist(input_data[-7, 2]) * as.matrix(fixed_score[-1])` should do

Comment: @DavidArenburg How can I get the gene name back in your final output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want this to be fast, simply work with matrices.

Lets create your matrices (how they should be in the first place)

```
input_mat <- as.matrix(input_data[-1])
row.names(input_mat) <- unlist(input_data[, 1])

fixed_mat <- as.matrix(fixed_score[-1])
row.names(fixed_mat) <- unlist(fixed_score[, 1])
```

Then, you can simply do

```
lapply(colnames(input_mat), function(x) input_mat[rownames(fixed_mat), x] * fixed_mat)

# [[1]]
#              B    Mac     NK    Neu   Stro
# Ncr1    0.7134 1.2382 4.0590 0.0164 0.0328
# Il1f9   0.4928 0.3168 0.0064 1.0656 0.0160
# Stfa2l1 0.4784 0.2553 0.0046 0.7636 0.0115
# Klra10  0.4675 0.7645 2.7280 0.0055 0.0220
# Dcn     0.2376 0.6444 0.0054 0.0054 1.7622
# Cxcr2   0.1716 0.4654 0.0039 0.0039 1.2727
# 
# [[2]]
#              B    Mac     NK    Neu   Stro
# Ncr1    0.8787 1.5251 4.9995 0.0202 0.0404
# Il1f9   3.1262 2.0097 0.0406 6.7599 0.1015
# Stfa2l1 0.0624 0.0333 0.0006 0.0996 0.0015
# Klra10  1.0200 1.6680 5.9520 0.0120 0.0480
# Dcn     0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
# Cxcr2   0.1452 0.3938 0.0033 0.0033 1.0769
```

This should be very fast

Answer (score 5):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
input_data %>% 
     #remove the 'Genes' column 
     select(-matches("Genes")) %>%
     #loop the other columns cbind with the Genes column
     map(~bind_cols(input_data['Genes'], Sample=.)) %>% 
     #left join with 'fixed_score' dataset by 'Genes'
     map(~left_join(fixed_score, ., by = "Genes")) %>%
     #multiply the columns selected in 'vars' with 'Sample'
     map(~mutate_at(., vars(B:Stro), funs(.*Sample))) %>%
     #remove the 'Sample' column from the list of tibbles
     map(~select(., -matches("Sample")))
#$Sample1
# A tibble: 6 × 6
#    Genes      B    Mac     NK    Neu   Stro
#    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    Ncr1 0.7134 1.2382 4.0590 0.0164 0.0328
#2   Il1f9 0.4928 0.3168 0.0064 1.0656 0.0160
#3 Stfa2l1 0.4784 0.2553 0.0046 0.7636 0.0115
#4  Klra10 0.4675 0.7645 2.7280 0.0055 0.0220
#5     Dcn 0.2376 0.6444 0.0054 0.0054 1.7622
#6   Cxcr2 0.1716 0.4654 0.0039 0.0039 1.2727

#$Sample2
# A tibble: 6 × 6
#    Genes      B    Mac     NK    Neu   Stro
#    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1    Ncr1 0.8787 1.5251 4.9995 0.0202 0.0404
#2   Il1f9 3.1262 2.0097 0.0406 6.7599 0.1015
#3 Stfa2l1 0.0624 0.0333 0.0006 0.0996 0.0015
#4  Klra10 1.0200 1.6680 5.9520 0.0120 0.0480
#5     Dcn 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
#6   Cxcr2 0.1452 0.3938 0.0033 0.0033 1.0769
```

Comment: thanks so much. One thing the sample name can be anything not starting with `Sample` and non gene fixed_score column can be anything not fixed like `B:Stro` can we generalize your code?

Comment: @neversaint If the 'Genes' name is the same, then `select(-matches("Genes"))`